# How to automatic display an editted datetime.now() in python?

Tags: python, datetime, edit

i am trying to do something very specific without using Pytz or messing with timezones.

```
horaactual = datetime.datetime.now()
#horaactual - 7 hours.
```

I would like to get the actual time with the exact second and then edit and change the hours to display 7 less hours, however i didn't seem to find an efficient way to do it and google always suggest timezones, wich is something i'd like to not use since this is a fixed time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract a [datetime.timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
horaactual = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=7)
```

Comment: oh, so simple and i didn't get it. All my tries were without using Timedelta :( Thank you for the answer :D I will accept this answer as soon as the system lets me (11 minutes)

Comment: @Saelyth: Sorry, you can accept only *one* answer! :-) Thanks for trying to accept both though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Just subtract 7 hours:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
in_the_past = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=7)
```